# Ultra-violet radiation and Bacteria in Petri Dishes

Tags: bacteriology

My partner and I are planning on doing a science fair project on how long bacteria can be exposed to UV radiation. We were wondering what the noticable effects would be if we held a UV lamp to bacterial colonies in petri dishes. Would the bacterial colonies shrink?

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. I have removed the word "question" from your title as all titles refer to questions. I also changed "rays" to "radiation". The former may be ok for a science fair, but it is not current scientific usage.

Comment: Think about what UV radiation does: It damages the DNA and thus the potential for the cells to *replicate*. If you blast them when replication is done and over, what do you expect to observe?

Comment: First of all, thank you both for editing my question and for the welcome.

Comment: I'd expect that the bacteria would no longer replicate.

Comment: A more interesting experiment would be to spread plate bacteria and irradiate them before they start actively growing. Then you can compare the effects of no radiation and different radiation on the amount of colonies formed.

Comment: I don't know if they would shrink. But, if it is possible for you to do an enumeration (perhaps by hemocytometry, if your school could provide the instruments) and serial dilution, you could test the percentage viability over time by standardizing an arbitrary cellular concentration (in cells/mL) to be spread plated.